# Why does -Wfatal-errors turn off notes about the error, and how do I turn notes back on?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I often build with `-Wfatal-errors` because I don't need an extra 100 meaningless errors while the compiler heroically tries to parse the rest of a source file after a typo that renders it meaningless.

However, I've noticed that this also turns off diagnostic notes about the fatal error itself.  For instance, with `-Wfatal-errors` I will get, say,

```
main.cpp:10:2: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'C'
  new C();
```

whereas if I don't have `-Wfatal-errors` on, I will get a note telling me which virtual method I forgot to implement:

```
class.hpp:15:2 note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'C':
class.hpp:28:6   void C::f()
```

Can I get these notes back while still keeping the behavior where I terminate after a single error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `-fmax-errors=1`. This will terminate compilation after the first error, but still show the notes for that error.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dehYbG) to compare the effects of these flags.